# Windows Defender Firewall is completely turned off, yet I still need to whitelist programs to let them work

Tags: windows-firewall, windows-defender

Discord was constantly connecting/disconnecting when I upgraded to Windows 10. I went into the settings and turned off all virus protection and firewalls. Not just at the top "disable" but I went through every setting and turned them off individually. After fighting with Discord for a bit, I added it to the firewall whitelist. Now it works. Clearly the firewall is still affecting things. Is there a way to truly remove/disable this Windows sponsored virus?

Comment: *Windows sponsored virus*... What virus?

Answer (score 1):

Checking the buttons to turn off windows defender doesn't truly turn it off. You have to use this process...

1. Open Start.
2. Search for gpedit.msc and click the top result to open the Local Group Policy Editor.
3. Browse the following path: Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Defender Antivirus

[image]

4. Select the Enabled option to disable Windows Defender Antivirus. Apply, then ok. Restart.

[image]